# How to configure mod_proxy_html with mod_proxy_balancer to resolve relative URLs

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-balancer, mod-proxy-html

I'm trying to configure mod_proxy_html such that my pages can resolve relative URLs. Apache runs normally with my config, but relative URLs are not resolved.

.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyHTMLEnable On

    Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
            BalancerMember "http://localhost:8080"
            BalancerMember "http://localhost:8180"
            ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / balancer://mycluster
    RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
</VirtualHost>
```

Result accessing jboss directly:

[image]

Result accessing jboss through apache's mod_proxy load balancing:

[image]

Evidently, no static resources are loaded in the latter due to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure "ProxyPassReverse" and "ProxyHTMLURLMap", and a trailing slash was needed at the end of the configured URLs. My configuration ended up like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster/>
            BalancerMember "http://localhost:8080"
            BalancerMember "http://localhost:8180"
            ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/ 
    ProxyHTMLURLMap balancer://mycluster/ /
    SetOutputFilter  proxy-html
    RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding

</VirtualHost>
```